# PHP empty response

Tags: php, apache, yii

I have an issue with PHP / Apache2 that i can't seem to figure out.
My application is running Yii framework. I have a method, customers/details which is suppose to return lot's of customer data for a given customer. For one of the customers however, i get an empty response. That is, no headers is received, no data what so ever. I've checked the Apache2 logs and nothing there is related to this. I know that the customer has lot's of data, but that shouldn't be the issue since there are customers with a lot more data than my particular customer that is struggling.

Where should i start my debugging? I get no errors in the logs, and absolutely no error message.

It "fails" at this row

```
$customer = Customers::model()->with('journals','journals.location','journals._template','locations','discount')->findByPk($id);
```

I never get past that particular line.

Comment: Can you post the code your using that is giving you an empty resource as a starting point please?

Comment: Take a look at your browsers debugging console and check the reply to the network request: I bet it is some error code, most likely code 500.

Comment: you should compare the users data to data of working users detail sites

Comment: It's a memory issue. You have too much items in your relations.

Comment: check the line again after removing those relations // `with`